# Keyup-Event added to eventlistener of HTML-input doesn't fire on keyup

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-tabs-app.
In one of my templates i got a div - called "div_mask_content" - in which i load a mask - containing some labels and inputs - by setting the InnerHtml-property of the div.
Because the div is reparsed after setting the InnerHtml-property i have to renew the keyup-event of the input-elements like this:

```
element.addEventListener('ng-keyup', $scope.onKeyUp);
```

I do this with a function, which tries to add the eventlistener to the function to be called on keyup.
Unfortunately the function onKeyUp is never called and i don't understand why.
So i tried to add a hardcoded input in my Ionic-template which calls the function onKeyUp by it's ng-keyup-event and this works as expected:

```
<input ng-keyup="onKeyUp()" />
```

Here is my template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Account">
    <ion-content>
        <div>
            <input ng-keyup="onKeyUp()" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="div_mask_content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar-footer">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:10px">
                            <ion-button id="btn_load_mask"
                                        class="button button-large button-positive"
                                        ng-click="load_mask()">Load mask</ion-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the code from the controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    // EventHandler for keyup-Event
    $scope.onKeyUp = function () {
        alert("keyup-Event was fired");
    };

    // Content der Maske wird geladen und Events wiederhergestellt
    $scope.load_mask = function () {
        var div_mask_content = document.getElementById("div_mask_content");

        if (div_mask_content != null) {
            alert("The content of the mask is loading");
            var mask_content = "<div id='content' class='list'><div class='item item-input-inset'><label>Value</label><input id='27' name='p16003_value' type='text' maxlength='7' placeholder='___,__' title='Please use format ###,##' pattern='^[+-]?\d{0,3}((\.|,)\d{1,2})?' /></div><div class='item item-input-inset'><label></label></div><div class='item item-input-inset'><label></label><input id='28' name='p16003_result' type='text' disabled maxlength='7' placeholder='___,__' title='Please use format ###,##' pattern='^[+-]?\d{0,3}((\.|,)\d{1,2})?' /></div></div>";
            div_mask_content.innerHTML = mask_content;

            // Renews the keyup-EventHandles of the input-elements
            renewKeyupEventHandle(div_mask_content);
        }

    };

    // Function for renewing the keyup-EventHandles of the input-elements
    var renewKeyupEventHandle = function (element) {
        if (element.nodeName == "INPUT") {
            // Here the function onKeyUp is added to the Event ng-keyup but will never be fired
            element.addEventListener('ng-keyup', $scope.onKeyUp);
        }

        if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var n = 0; n < element.childElementCount; n++) {
                renewKeyupEventHandle(element.childNodes.item(n));
            }
        }

    };

});
```

I have to guess i'm actually a little bit perplexed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use ng-keyup

Comment: you don't need `element.addEventListener('ng-keyup', $scope.onKeyUp);`

Comment: I don't need AddEventListener for the hardcoded input, but for the ones which are loaded by setting the InnerHtml-property of the div called "div_mask_content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
element.addEventListener('keyup', $scope.onKeyUp);
```

(`'ng-keyup'` is not a native JS event)

but you better use the "angular way"

```
<input ng-keyup="onKeyUp()" />
```

Comment: You are right, Elad. Thank You very much for the solution! I'm still new to Ionic and find it's difference - per example - between keyup and ng-keyup a little bit tricky.